# Clojure: map map

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I would like to use the map function on map.  But I can't get it to work.

A toy example:

```
(map map [+ - *] [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9])
```

I expect a result like (12 15 18) but all I get is an error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to map each of the operator separately over the lists, then use

```
((fn [ops & args] (map #(apply map %1 args) ops)) [+ - *] [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9])
```

or if you are willing to reorder arguments

```
(map #(map %1 [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]) [+ - *])
```

Both give the result of `((12 15 18) (-10 -11 -12) (28 80 162))`

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to already existing answers, you could replace the outer `map` with a list comprehension, which is more readable than a nested `map` IMHO:

```
user=> (defn fun [ops & args]
  #_=>     (for [op ops]
  #_=>         (apply map op args)))
#'user/fun

user=> (fun [+ - *] [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9])
((12 15 18) (-10 -11 -12) (28 80 162))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `juxt`:

`(apply map list (map (juxt + - *) [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]))`

Which will result in: `((12 15 18) (-10 -11 -12) (28 80 162))`